# Sound input issue with Asus X551CA, Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Tags: 18.04, sound

I am using a Asus X551CA laptop, with Ubuntu 18.04 LTS. Now, the laptop comes with a single audio jack for input and output. But whenever I am connecting any headset to it, only the audio output is coming and the microphone is not detected. The headset is completely functional as I have checked it on other devices.

Please suggest how to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

This is apparently a really common problem with these Asus machines that share a mic/headphone jack. This was actually the first time I had even heard of anyone doing that. In any case, Asus support recommends using USB headphones if you need to use the mic as well. That, or a headset with three segments in the plug (that is, three segments in the jack you plug into the machine). Here is a link to a forum where several other users chased this down: [Asus Combo headphone/Mic jack issues](https://forums.tomsguide.com/threads/asus-notebook-mic-problem.344702/)

It's a Windows forum, but if you scroll down towards the bottom they get into the part where they contacted Asus directly and that was their recommendation to solve the problem.

Comment: Actually my problem is with the microphone of the headset. The internal microphone is working well and good. But I want the headset microphone to work. How to do that?

Comment: That's what I was talking about in my answer. You will either need to use a headset/mic combo that is connected with USB or a headset/mic combo that has three segments in the plug. From everything I've read, you wont be able to use your current headset/mic with that laptop. You will only be able to use one function at a time. It's just a limitation of the laptop hardware that I imagine they took to cut down on costs.